# Python threading, new thread gets stuck

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, pygtk

I'm trying to write a python application with a gui, and I'm having trouble with python's threading package.

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import threading
import time

class gui:
    def main(self):
        print "starting gui"
        gtk.main()

class logic:
    def __call__(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        print "did logic"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(None, logic()).start()
    gui().main()
```

Outputs:

```
starting gui
```

The logic never happens. Why? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dealt with this problem for the longest of times, here's where you'll find a solution:

http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq20.006.htp

Comment: Wow, that is pretty complicated. Could anyone recommend another gui library that allows me to use another thread without recompiling it?

Comment: You don't have to recompile GTK to use threads. All distributions I know of have GTK compiled with thread support, including the GTK installers on windows. And if you only access the GUI from the main thread (e.g. by sending messages to the thread, using idle_add, etc.), you don't even need `threads_enter`/`threads_leave`.